# Can a person hear hours after dying?

Tags: sensation, sensory-perception, death

A person close to me passed away recently in the hospital. About 2 and a half hours after clinical death<sup>*</sup>, the nurse told us that they could still hear<sup>**</sup> us and encouraged us to keep on talking to the deceased at this time.

However, this doesn't make sense to me. I looked it up online, but could only find articles stating that people can hear for a few seconds after clinical death<sup>*</sup>, because not all the brain cells have died yet. So is it true that you can hear for hours following your death, when your heart has not been beating for hours and you have not been breathing for hours?

<sub><sup>*</sup> *Clinical death is defined as the moment when the heart stops beating and a person stops breathing. From what I can read, clinical death leads to biological death within about 10 minutes, when the lack of blood and oxygen to the brain lead to the gradual death of brain cells.*</sub>

<sub><sup>**</sup> *To hear is to perceive auditory stimulation in both the physical sense and the cognitive sense in this context. In other words, the sensory apparatuses are still functional, and the mind is receiving the sound and can understand it.*</sub>